# Other mouse buttons and ActiveX

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, activex

I'm trying to pick up the forward and back buttons being pressed in an **ActiveX** control (ie) but I'm having no luck finding what value they are.

Is **TranslateAccelerator** the correct place to pick this up? And what are the defines that represent the extra mouse buttons?

Comment: Is this one question? Seem to be asking about mouse buttons in one section and some custom buttons belonging to an active X in another. What specifically are you trying to do and how?

Comment: pick up the other mouse buttons (i.e. mouse3, mouse4, mouse5) in an activex control